# Inserting data into a WordPress table on form submit, using PHP

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I have a form with some fields, and a wpdb table which corresponds to the fields. I want the data from the form to be submitted into the table when the submit button is clicked on the form.

Here is the form:

```
function display_form(){
echo '
<form action="insertrow.php" method="post">
<p>Ticket id:  <br />
User id: <br /> 
Description: <textarea class="widget" rows="4" cols="1" 
name="ticket_description"></textarea>
Priority: <select name="ticket_priority" placeholder="Select">
<option value="critical">Critical</option>
<option value="urgent">Urgent</option>
<option value="important">Important</option>
<option value="standard" selected>Standard</option>
</select>
Status: <select name="ticket_status" placeholder="Select">
<option value="planned">Planned</option>
<option value="in progress">In Progress</option>
<option value="on hold">On Hold</option>
<option value="completed">Completed</option>
<option value="ready for invoice">Ready for Invoice</option>
<option value="to be invoiced as per attached">To be invoiced as per  
attached</option>
</select>
</p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form> 
';
}
```

the form calls the insertrow.php file:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
insert_row();
}

function insert_row()
{
global $wpdb;
require_once('../../../wp-config.php');
$tablename =  'st_support_ticket';

$data = array( 
'ticket_id' => '1', 
'ticket_user_id' => '1', 
'ticket_description' => $_POST['ticket_description'] ,
'ticket_priority' => $_POST['ticket_priority'],
'ticket_status' => $_POST['ticket_status'] );

$wpdb->insert($tablename, $data);
}
```

Just trying to get this to enter the description, priority and status into the st_support_ticket table.

At the moment when I click submit the url suffix changes to insertrow.php and displays a blank page. The data is not entered into table (checking by opening it up in phpmyadmin).

Am I missing something?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I was curious what you are expecting to see on the page when you post the data? Per: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb this looks correct.

Comment: Also did you want those ids to be strings? `'ticket_id' => '1'` vs `'ticket_id' => 1`. Might make a difference.

Comment: Not really what you're asking about, but you might want to look into leveraging custom post types instead of using your own custom table. Depending on the nature of your project, custom post types could save you a lot of time because WP will generate the admin UI for you, and you can leverage other tools like `WP_Query`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the WordPress way.  There's several issues, but let's start high-level.

**Note:** This answer assumes that you are working on the *front-end*, not on the dasboard.

First, your form tag should NOT point to a specific file.  You should modify your form to point back to the page it is on.  The lazy (not ideal) way to do this is to leave the "action" of the form tag empty. This will cause the form to post back to the same page / url it is displayed on:

`<form method="post" action="">`

Then, find your theme functions.php file, or your plugin main file, and "include" the insertrow.php file:

`require_once "insertrow.php;`

Then, you need to change your "watch" a bit so that it's a FAR more unique value than "submit".  Since your form contains a select with the name of `ticket_priority`, I would suggest watching for that:

```
if(isset($_POST['ticket_priority']))
{
insert_row();
}
```

And, if you do this the way I'm suggesting, you won't have to include the WP code

```
// Comment the below line out.  Not necessary.
// require_once('../../../wp-config.php');
```

Lastly - on a WP site, you want to take advantage of the WordPress security tools that are in place.  Using a NONCE input is a bare minimum to help ensure that the form was legitimately posted, rather than being spammed in.  Check out [wp_nonce_field](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nonce_field) and [wp_verify_nonce](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_verify_nonce).

Done more inline with the "WordPress way", your code would look something like so:

```
function display_form(){
    echo '
    <form action="" method="post">';
    // Add a nonce field
    wp_nonce_field('MyNonceAction', 'ticket_nonce');
    echo '
    <p>Ticket id:  <br />
    User id: <br /> 
    Description: <textarea class="widget" rows="4" cols="1" 
    name="ticket_description"></textarea>
    Priority: <select name="ticket_priority" placeholder="Select">
    <option value="critical">Critical</option>
    <option value="urgent">Urgent</option>
    <option value="important">Important</option>
    <option value="standard" selected>Standard</option>
    </select>
    Status: <select name="ticket_status" placeholder="Select">
    <option value="planned">Planned</option>
    <option value="in progress">In Progress</option>
    <option value="on hold">On Hold</option>
    <option value="completed">Completed</option>
    <option value="ready for invoice">Ready for Invoice</option>
    <option value="to be invoiced as per attached">To be invoiced as per  
    attached</option>
    </select>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form> 
    ';
}
```

And the below code is included in your theme / plugin core files, NOT in a stand-alone file:

```
if(isset($_POST['ticket_priority']))
{
    // Debugging output, since you are having troubles finding the issue.
    // If this doesn't fire, then you've got a problem with the select name or this code isn't included in your theme / plugin.
    echo "SAVING ENTRY";
    // Get the nonce value for validation
    $nonce = $_POST['ticket_nonce'];
    // If the nonce does not verify, do NOT process the form.
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce($nonce, 'MyNonceAction')) {
         // If this spits out an error, that means the nonce failed
         echo 'Security error. Do not process the form.';
         return;
    }

    insert_row();
}

function insert_row()
{

    // You should use the WP table prefixes, so let's set that up....
    global $wpdb, $table_prefix;
    $tablename =  $table_prefix . 'st_support_ticket';

    $data = array( 
    'ticket_id' => '1', 
    'ticket_user_id' => '1', 
    'ticket_description' => $_POST['ticket_description'] ,
    'ticket_priority' => $_POST['ticket_priority'],
    'ticket_status' => $_POST['ticket_status'] );

    // Debugging: Lets see what we're trying to save
    var_dump($data);

    // FOR database SQL injection security, set up the formats
    $formats = array( 
        '%d', // ticket_id should be an integer
        '%d', // ticket_user_id should be an integer
        '%s', // ticket_description should be a string
        '%s', // ticket_priority should be an string
        '%s'  // ticket_status should be an string 
    ); 

    // Debugging: Turn on error reporting for db to see if there's a database error
    $wpdb->show_errors();
    // Actually attempt to insert the data
    $wpdb->insert($tablename, $data, $formats);
}
```

Comment: Hi cale_b, thank you for your answer. I have implemented all of the code you suggested but am getting a: Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_verify_nonce(). Am I missing something again?

Comment: @mgrantnz - sounds like you haven't included the file / functions above (via a "require_once") within your active theme's or plugin.  This code needs to run in the full context of the WP plugin / theme, otherwise none of those functions (including $wpdb) are available.

Comment: I removed the nonce part to test the functionality, but it still will not insert anything into the database. do you have any clues why this is happening? The submit button now just refreshes the page.

Comment: @mgrantnz What have you done to troubleshoot?  See some edits to test if things are getting fired / output errors.

Comment: Ok so i have done some testing and found this error: "WordPress database error: [Table 'wordpress.wp_st_support_ticket' doesn't exist]". This occurs when the insert() function is being called. The table clearly exists in phpmyadmin

Comment: @mgrantnz - well, if WP says it doesn't exist, then it doesn't, or it's not in the right database.  So, that's the first issue you need to sort out with respect to the records not writing.  Are you sure the table has the `wp_` prefix, and is actually named **wp_st_support_ticket**?